# How do I fold by "{" in Sublime Text 3 if I have an array of JSON objects?

Tags: sublimetext3

If I have the following array of JSON objects in Sublime, it will collapse at any "[". My ask is if this can be changed to fold at any "{"

Taking this JSON array

```
[{"a":[{"b":1,"c":2},{"d":3},{"x":99,"y":100}],"b":4},{"a":[{"b":5,"c":6}],"b":7}]
```

and pretty formatting it within the same file

```
[
  {
    "a": [
      {
        "b": 1,
        "c": 2
      },
      {
        "d": 3
      },
      {
        "x": 99,
        "y": 100
      }
    ],
    "b": 4
  },
  {
    "a": [
      {
        "b": 5,
        "c": 6
      }
    ],
    "b": 7
  }
]
```

As an example of it working mostly the way I am looking for, with the JSON below, it will collapse at any "{" with more than one element, so {"d":3} does not collapse:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "b": 1,
      "c": 2
    },
    {
      "d": 3
    },
    {
      "x": 99,
      "y": 100
    }
  ],
  "b": 4
}
```

Edit - it looks like if I take the formatted array into a new file, it will recognize all potential folding points.

Comment: In the second example that you gave, the section with `"b": 1, "c": 2` collapses, as does the section with `"x": 99, "y": 100`. I'm not sure what your problem is...

Comment: Updated to make it consistent. Just noticed that if I copy/paste these formatted JSON into a new file it will recognize any folding points. Usually I am pretty formatting a single line, and that is when I run into an issue. I guess I have a workaround